# What CMFs (aka Spectral Functions) did Microsoft and HP use to develop sRGB standardized in: IEC 61966-2-1:1999?

Tags: color-science, color-management, colorspace

CIE 1931 2° probably served as a basis, but which version?

Published in 1999, the final specification can not have referred to CIE 2006, but [cvrl.org lists several others](http://www.cvrl.org/cmfs.htm): CIE 1931 2°, CIE 1931 2° Judd 1951, or CIE 1931 2° Judd 1951 and Vos 1978?  It also provides variants of CIE 1931 at 5 nano meter or 1 nano meter wavelength step sizes.  If the spec ignored updated CMFs, which resolution underpins sRGB?

How about for other spaces like Adobe RGB 1998, Apple RGB, and P3-Display?

How does one go about determining which CMFs underlie color spaces in general?